# Member CComPtr in a C++/CLR class

Tags: c++, com, clr

I'm writing a C++/CLI class that needs to hold on to `CComPtr` for the duration of its lifefime, e.g.

```
public ref class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        CComPtr<ISomeType> pSomeType;
        // init someType;
        m_pSomeType = pSomeType;
    }

private:
    CComPtr<ISomeType> m_pSomeType;

    void DoSomething()
    {
        m_pSomeType->DoSomething();
    }
}
```

However this doesn't compile as mixed types are not supported - the solution is to use an [`AutoPtr`](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2007/03/26/AutoPtr.aspx).  I still need reference counting and so this is what I came up with.

```
public ref class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        CComPtr<ISomeType> pSomeType;
        // init someType;
        m_pSomeType = new CComPtr<ISomeType>(pSomeType);
    }

private:
    AutoPtr<CComPtr<ISomeType>> m_pSomeType;

    void DoSomething()
    {
        CComPtr<ISomeType> pSomeType = *m_pSomeType.GetPointer();
        pSomeType->DoSomething();
    }
}
```

This looks nasty to me, and I also suspect that its wrong in some way (I come from a C# background so I'm kind of learning a lot of this as I go).

How should I "store" a `CComPtr` as a member of a C++/CLR class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a smart pointer that might help you.  It can't be used to manage COM pointers directly, but it can be used to hold a CComPtr inside a managed class.

- [scoped_ptr for C++/CLI (ensure managed object properly frees owned native object)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1695/scoped-ptr-for-c-cli-ensure-managed-object-properly-frees-owned-native-object)

Please respect the license requirements if you choose to use it (commercial use is not prohibited, but you must give credit).

Also, you can write

```
(*m_pSomeType)->DoSomething();
```

instead of copying the `CComPtr` (which has to update the reference count).

Besides that, I would use the *ctor-initializer-list* instead of assignment in the constructor.

```
MyClass()
    : m_pSomeType(new CComPtr<ISomeType>)
{
}
```

Comment: This looks very similar to the `AutoPtr` class that I'm already using, unless this offers some advantages that I'm not seeing?

Comment: @Justin: Mine is better than Kenny Kerr's `AutoPtr` in the same way that `std::unique_ptr` and `boost::scoped_ptr` are better than `std::auto_ptr`.  He copied all the design flaws from `std::auto_ptr`.

Comment: Okay, sounds like I need to read up on that.  How should I use these smart pointers with CComBPtr (and related) types?  Is the approach I have used OK, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile managed and unmanaged code seperately then [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0adb9zxe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a link.

Using this you can retain flavour of both.